# Apache Never runs after configuring eAccelerator and FastCGI

Tags: php, apache-2.2, fastcgi, php5

I recently configured accelerator and fastcgi with apache using: http://secure-ubuntu-server.blogspot.com/2009/07/howto-performance-tuning-of-lamp-and.html

Now my Apache never starts.

Logs shows:

```
Mon Jul 20 16:12:24 2009] [notice] ModSecurity for Apache/2.5.6 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Mon Jul 20 16:12:25 2009] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 10919)
[Mon Jul 20 16:12:25 2009] [alert] FastCGI: read() from pipe failed (0)
[Mon Jul 20 16:12:25 2009] [alert] FastCGI: the PM is shutting down, Apache seems to have disappeared - bye
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the exact version of PHP you're using? eAccelerator isn't compatible with PHP 5.3 - honestly, I'd strongly recommend APC or XCache above eAccelerator.

Answer (score 0):

Try running an Apache instance directly from the command line (i.e. run `/usr/sbin/apache2` or whatever the HTTPD executable is) to see if you get any more feedback (like, say, `Segmentation fault`).

Comment: nope, nothing is printed on command line. All i get is messages in error log. I have also posted in that blog for support request.

Comment: Its the problem with eaccelerator i think because as soon as i comment "extension=" in php.ini, apache starts working...

Comment: What happens when you uncomment the eaccelerator extension and run `php -v` from command line?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'll post here.

Probably, php is causing a segmentation fault and hence apache is dying.
If you're using php-cgi in FcgidWrapper or something else, however you configured php with fastcgi, try running that thing directly from the command line.

For instance, /usr/bin/php-cgi.

If you have configured it using the Action directive, ensure that the wrapper has the executable bit set.

Answer (score 0):

try running the apache binary from the shell with strace:

strace -f /usr/sbin/apache2 > /tmp/outfile

or whatever your binary is. After that check the file with less or tail to check the last entries that happend before the apache dies (shortly before the error message is written in the log).

less /tmp/outfile